# backpack for laravel getting link id

Tags: laravel-backpack

i need to export an specific record into pdf , so i created a inline button using addbuttomfrommodel function, now i need to pass the id of the specific record to the model where the route is created, how can it be done?

[image]

In model i have problem to pass the record ID in the href.so i can export only the specific record.
in model

```
public function getExportarButton() {

  return  "<a class='btn btn-primary' href='exportar_ficha'>Exportar A Documento</a>"; 
}
```

thanks ini advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry object is available in your custom blade file as $entry